# plain react router v4

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4

It's possible create plain routes in `react-router` v4?
Ex (v3 version):

```
const routes = {
  path: '/',
  indexRoute: {onEnter: (nextState, replace) => replace('/calendar')},
  childRoutes: [
    {path: '/calendar', component: CalendarContainer},
    {path: '/booking/:id', component: BookingContainer}
  ]
};
```

Comment: Similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52459765/child-route-is-not-displaying-react-router/52460645#52460645

Comment: Have you already looked over the [official docs](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/philosophy) and found nothing or any example that doesn't help you in your case? It would be better if you add the code that you have tried and the error that you are having so the community can help you.